# Objects without titles cannot be created via the Facebook Object API

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

According to this [document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/titleless-objects/), the Open Graph API supports creating objects without specifying the `og:title` property. I'm using the Object API, and since the objects I'm defining don't have meaningful titles, I presumed that I could do the same by just not including a 'title' field in my request.

The request I'm sending (via the Graph API Explorer) is equivalent to this:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/namespace:foo
     object={
       "image": "http://cdn.example.com/images/bar/l",
       "url": "http://example.com/photos/baz?image=bar",
       "description": "Image caption",
       "site_name": "Example"
     }
```

Except, the response I keep getting is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Object Missing a Required Value: Object at URL 'http://example.com/photos/baz?image=bar' of type 'namespace:foo' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

So, is it not possible at all to create objects without titles via the Object API? Does this only apply to self-hosted objects?